# Search and Find

Tags: excel, vba

Instead of on column performing, I want on two adjacent columns

For example looking columns N:M side by side cells and compare with columns B:C side by side cells if matched then go on.

```vb
Sub Find()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long, lRow As Long, lRow1 As Long
Dim rgFound As Range
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp).Row
lRow1 = Cells(Rows.Count, "n").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lRow
Set rgFound = Range("n2", "n" & lRow1).Find(Cells(i, "b"), LookIn:=xlValues)
If rgFound Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "not found"
Else
Cells(i, "l") = rgFound.Offset(, 2).Value
End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What should I do to get an answer to my question sooner?

Comment: a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) is the only way really.

Answer (score 0):

### A VBA Lookup: Multiple Adjacent Columns

[image]

```vb
Sub LookupData()
    
    Const SRC_FIRST_LOOKUP_ROW As String = "M2:N2"
    Const SRC_RETURN_COL As String = "P"
    Const DST_FIRST_LOOKUP_ROW As String = "B2:C2"
    Const DST_RETURN_COL As String = "I"
    Const COL_DELIMITER As String = "@"
    Const NOT_FOUND_VALUE As Variant = ""
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim lCell As Range, lrg As Range, rrg As Range, lData(), rData()
    Dim r As Long, rCount As Long, lc As Long, lcCount As Long, rStr As String
    
    ' Source
    
    With ws.Range(SRC_FIRST_LOOKUP_ROW)
        Set lCell = .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data
        lcCount = .Columns.Count
        rCount = lCell.Row - .Row + 1
        Set lrg = .Resize(rCount)
    End With
    
    lData = lrg.Value
    
    Set rrg = lrg.EntireRow.Columns(SRC_RETURN_COL)
    If rCount = 1 Then
        ReDim rData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): rData(1, 1) = rrg.Value
    Else
        rData = rrg.Value
    End If
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        rStr = CStr(lData(r, 1))
        For lc = 2 To lcCount
            rStr = rStr & COL_DELIMITER & CStr(lData(r, lc))
        Next lc
        If Not dict.Exists(rStr) Then dict(rStr) = rData(r, 1)
    Next r
    
    ' Destination
    
    With ws.Range(DST_FIRST_LOOKUP_ROW)
        Set lCell = .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data
        rCount = lCell.Row - .Row + 1
        Set lrg = .Resize(rCount)
    End With
    
    lData = lrg.Value
    
    Set rrg = lrg.EntireRow.Columns(DST_RETURN_COL)
    ReDim rData(1 To rCount, 1 To 1)
        
    ' Result
        
    For r = 1 To rCount
        rStr = CStr(lData(r, 1))
        For lc = 2 To lcCount
            rStr = rStr & COL_DELIMITER & CStr(lData(r, lc))
        Next lc
        If dict.Exists(rStr) Then
            rData(r, 1) = dict(rStr)
        Else
            rData(r, 1) = NOT_FOUND_VALUE
        End If
    Next r
    
    rrg.Value = rData
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Data lookup has finished.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: you are super cool VBasic2008